# No Credentials error with python , common data crawl

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, common-crawl

I am trying out a sample common data crawl example based on
https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/03/analyzing-the-web-for-the-price-of-a-sandwich.html

I am running this below command in my local windows PC based on the instructions.

```
python mr_crawl_phonenumbers.py -r emr s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2014-52/wet.paths.gz s3://yelp/business_data.txt
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

I am new to this, Do I need to set any credentials. If yes, how to set this up in local PC.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Boto3 doc: [Credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) - To get access to AWS you need login and password - and your script need it too. You have to register program on AWS and get ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, SESSION_TOKEN which works like login,password for your program.

Comment: @furas I tried this, now I am getting the below exception `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

Comment: did you register program on AWS ? Did you get ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, SESSION_TOKEN from AWS ?

Comment: @furas I created a user on AWS IAM and got the `ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY` and then tried `aws configure` and added `ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY` but there is no option to add `SESSION_TOKEN`.